# CiviCRM installer reports Warning: CRM_Core_ClassLoader message

Tags: installation

I'm trying to set up a new CiviCRM install (4.7.24 plus Drupal 7.56) on a subdomain but I keep getting an error message.

I tried to install using the Drupal 'add a module' but after about a minute it just brings up a blank screen, and when I check the files online, nothing has been uploaded.

Then I tried to (slowly) ftp the files, but then when I run .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php I get an error message along the lines of:

Warning: CRM_Core_ClassLoader::require_once(./vendor/autoload.php) [crm-core-classloader.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/sites/t//public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 107

Fatal error: CRM_Core_ClassLoader::require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/sites/t//public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 107

I'm not sure what I'm missing - is it because I'm installing on a subdomain? Can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the cause? I've just noticed under the Drupal modules list a message to say the PHP version is insufficient (see screenshot). I presume this would hinder the install.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, updated the PHP and then everything installed without a hitch.